# calling RedirectFromLoginPage but not redirecting to ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

When a anonymous user tries to access a page that requires authentication, I redirect to the login controller/action:

```
/user/login?ReturnUrl=/blah/do
```

Upon logging in, I do:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Id.ToString(), false);
```

The debugger shows that this line does get called.

But then I get redirected to default.aspx (defaultUrl), not the url in the RedirectUrl querystring param.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Post the code for your login page?  I think we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the route for /blah/do exists. If it can't find it then it is going to redirect to the default page.